# Getting txpool with python web3 and infura

Tags: transactions, web3.py, python, pending-transactions, txpool

I am trying to monitor pending transactions with python web3 and an infura node. I am currently using `web3.eth.getBlock(block_identifier='pending', full_transactions=True)` on a loop to fetch pending transactions, but it seems to be missing some transactions and completely ignores transactions with lower gas prices.

I have tried using `w3.eth.filter('pending')` but that just gives an error
`ValueError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method eth_newPendingTransactionFilter does not exist/is not available'}`

Is there any way to access the full txpool on python with an infura node?

Comment: Did you find the solution?
I'm trying to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Infura doesn't support TxPool https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/55. You can accomplish this by running your own node.